# Draw application that sends what user draws to others

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, chat

Imagine a canvas paint tool where you can draw and paint on a website, but like a chat application, what you draw immediately shows up on your friend's canvas as well. WebSockets would be more that perfect for this. But since my website is being hosted by a web hotel that doesn't support JavaScript on the server, WebSockets is not an option (if I understood it correctly). Is there any other way I could build it - that almost keeps the efficiency that WebSockets provide? Or is my only good solution to host my web site on a server that let's me run JavaScript, (suck as note.js)?

Comment: Something as incredibly custom and involved as this should definitely use a server which you have complete control over. I would love to see this in action once you get it running!

Comment: FYI: WebSockets is supported by more than Node.JS. Long polling techniques are generally the fallback for when sockets aren't available.

Comment: There are even PHP options for WebSockets ... but they are likely not supported by your current web host: http://socketo.me/docs/deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next best solution for sharing the canvas data in real-time, would be ajax long polling. Simply put, the client makes an ajax request to the server, if the server has fresh canvas data it returns the data, otherwise it keeps the HTTP request open until it has new data to return. Once data is returned, the process is repeated.

Since we are using standard HTTP requests, this wont be as efficient as web-sockets, as every HTTP request carries a bunch of headers which are not needed.

More on long polling - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

I should add, WebSockets is not specific to NodeJs. WebSockets is a protocol which can be implemented in any language. There are libraries available for using WebSockets in a variety of different languages, including PHP, which I assume your server supports.

Comment: Thank you. Would it work fine on a site with a few hundred visitors using the application? I can live with it not being as efficient as WebSockets, just as long as it actually works with a lot of people using the application simultaneously.

Comment: I see not reason why not. Facebook chat uses long-polling, and that seems to scale just fine. Socket.io actually uses long-polling as a fallback, when web-sockets are not supported by the client.

Comment: See - https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=14218138919

Comment: @lawls- if you're relying on a shared-hosting plan for PHP, then the answer would very likely be "no, it won't work with a lot of people using the application." Even if you used Node.JS, you may find that you'd be exceeding the capacity of basic hosting plans.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for http://tutorialzine.com/2012/08/nodejs-drawing-game/

Comment: Not sure this is an answer to my question. I pointed out that I can't run node.js since my host won't allow JavaScript on the server. And you provide a tutorial that uses node.js?

Comment: I would find a cheap host that will allow you to use node.js!